# Flutter Map Is there any way two add two different values with same key name

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

Flutter Map

in this value of i is changing

```
    mapList.addAll({
          'item_name[]':shopping_item_name[i],
          'item_description[]':shopping_quantity[i],
          'item_price[]':shopping_unitPrice[i],
        });
```

Looking for output like this
{'item_name[]': 'Arpit', 'item_name[]': 'Rnjeet', 'item_name[]': 'Prabhat', 'item_name[]': 'Rohan',
'item_description[]': '2', 'item_description[]': '3', 'item_description[]': '10', 'item_description[]': '3',
'item_price[]': '1', 'item_price[]': '1', 'item_price[]': '1', 'item_price[]': '1',}

Comment: it is not possible, why do you want to do that?

Comment: stuck in api and API wants this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to set same keys in the same Map, think about making it a `Map<String, List<String>>` where you will hold all values with the same key on a `List<String>`, like this:

```
void main() {
  final myMap = <String, List<int>>{};

  addValue(myMap, 'key1', 1);
  addValueToMap(myMap, 'key1', 24);
  addValueToMap(myMap, 'key2', 35);
  addValueToMap(myMap, 'key1', 12);
  addValueToMap(myMap, 'key2', 112);

  
  print(myMap); // {key1: [1, 24, 12], key2: [35, 112],}
}

     void addValue<K, V>(Map<K, List<V>> map, K key, V value) =>
    map.update(key, (list) => list..add(value), ifAbsent: () => [value]
      );
```